# Retrieve data from second sql table inside a modal using php

Tags: php, sql

So the question would be, how can I retrieve data for Locatie (drop-down list) inside the modal if the data is in a second table named locationstbl with the column named address in sql.

There might be some way to use JOIN or something like that just to display the data I need in that dropdown list ?

Thank you.

Here's the code.

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Locatie</th>
              <th>Serie Aparat</th>
              <th>Tip Joc</th>
              <th>Cabinet</th>
              <th>Data Expirare</th>
              <th>Actiuni</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>



 <?php


    $sql = "SELECT location, serial, game_type, cabinet, date 
            FROM all_machines 
            ORDER BY location ASC";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $resultNum = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    $counter = 1;
    if ($resultNum > 0) {
        while ($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc ($result)){
            $location = $row['location'];
            $serial = $row['serial'];
            $game_type = $row['game_type'];
            $cabinet = $row['cabinet'];
            $date = $row['date'];



?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $counter++;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $location;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $serial;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $game_type;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $cabinet;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $date;?></td>
            <td>    

                    <!-- Table Action Buttons -->
                <a href="#editare<?php echo $serial;?>" data-toggle="modal">
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-whatever="<?php echo $serial;?>">Editare</button></a> 

                <a href="#delete<?php echo $serial;?>" data-toggle="modal">
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' >Sterge</button></a>

                <a href='detalii.php?id=<?php echo $serial;?>'>
                    <button type='button' class='btn btn-info btn-sm'>Detalii</button></a>

            </td>


        <!--Delete Modal -->
<div id="delete<?php echo $serial; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">                     
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmati stergerea</h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <input type="hidden" name="serial" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>">
                        <div class="alert alert-danger"><p>Sunteti sigur ca doriti stergerea seriei <strong><?php echo $serial; ?></strong> ?</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $serial;?>">Sterge</a>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Anuleaza</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>



                <!--Edit Modal -->
<div id="editare<?php echo $serial; ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">                     
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Editare Serie: <strong><?php echo $serial; ?></strong></h4>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <form method="POST" action="edit-mac.php?id=<?php echo $serial;?>">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="form-row">
                                    <!-- Select data from locationstbl -->
                                    <div class='col-md-6'>
                                        <label>Locatie</label>
                                        <select name='location' class='form-control input-sm'>
                                            <option></option>
                                        </select>
                                        <span class='help-block'></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label for="serial">Serie</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="serialup" name="serialup" value="<?php echo $serial; ?>">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label for="serial">Tip Joc</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="game_type" name="game_type" value="<?php echo $game_type; ?>">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label for="serial">Cabinet</label>
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="cabinet" name="cabinet" value="<?php echo $cabinet; ?>">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <label for="date">Data expirare</label>
                                        <input class="form-control" id="date" type="text" autocomplete="off" name="date" value="<?php echo $date; ?>" placeholder="LL-AAAA">
                                        <span class="help-block"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>    
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">Actualizeaza</button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal">Anuleaza</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</div>



        </tr>
<?php
    }
}
?>   


          </tbody>     
        </table>
```

Comment: you could make an ajax request to the server to get the relevant extra data and put it into the modal using Javascript. That's one option.

Comment: I don't really know anything about AJAX, I'm a newbie, but I'll look into that, thank you.

Comment: it's just a way of making a HTTP request using JavaScript, to load some extra content (or send extra data to the server, or both) without having to refresh the whole page. There are zillions of tutorials, examples, previous StackOverflow questions etc. etc. available online about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a possible answer, I would like to warn you to start thinking about adopting a PHP development framework and taking advantage of its advantages. Mixing PHP with HTML is counterproductive and difficult to maintain in the long run.
You have two ways to do it:

1. Do a SQL query to the second table like the first and get the information only for the dropdown: `$locaties = "SELECT * FROM locationstbl"`
   Going through this solution, where you have the dropdown will look something like this:

```html
<div class='col-md-6'>
    <label>Locatie</label>
    <select name='location' class='form-control input-sm'>
        <?php foreach($locaties as $locatie){ ?>
            <option><?php echo $locatie ?></option> 
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
    <span class='help-block'></span>
</div>
```

2. Do a single search with an INNER JOIN and get the information from the location table + the locationstbl table information as long as there is a foreign key.

Comment: I managed to do it with first option after a bit of struggling. Thank you.